# Java class in android studio does not appeared as functions but only tags

Tags: java, android, class

Can anyone tell me why my java class looks like this it was fine and display functions but i don't know what happened .anyone can help me please ..

[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXncK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are saying and screenshot shows that HolderActivity.java, but code doesn't looks like java file. It looks like some xml file in right side of pic. *If it is not mentioned java file , then you may excluded/closed java file from the project. If it is the problem right click and include java file. If you cant include it open that java file in notepad and copy paste the code in new created file.*

If showed pic is the code, its not java file. May be the extension will different than name showed. See other files, they don't have extension still those are java files right. So check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SARATH V , I opened the java file in notepad and i found my functions and variable ,I don't know why this happened but its solve my problem

Comment: Ok @hassanemad, if it works you may accidentally excluded the java file from project. You are welcome.